# JavaScript Filter Loop Not Looping Through All Item In Array

Tags: javascript

In the following code I am trying to filter the data. However, I see in the algorithm that it loops through the first item in the `userPassedFilter` array and returns the filtered data but doesn't loop again to check the second item in the `userPassedFilter` array. I know this is happening because I call return true before it iterates through the entire `userPassedFilter` array. How can I assure that in the algorythm that it loops through all the items in the `userPassedFilter` before returning the final result?

```
**User Selected Filter**
let userPassedFilter = [{"phase":1},{"phase":2}]
```

```
**Data**
let dataList = [
{"voltage":35, "phase":2},
{"voltage":12, "phase":2},
{"voltage":12, "phase":3},
{"voltage":35, "phase":1}
]
```

```
**Filter Data Algorithm** 
module.exports = {

  filterData: (dataList, userPassedFilter)=>{
    let filteredData = [];

    filteredData = dataList.filter((data) =>{
    for(let item of userPassedFilter){
        for(let key in item){
          if(data[key] === undefined || data[key] !== item[key])
          return false
        }
        


      }
return true
    })

return filteredData

}
}
```

Comment: move the `return true` out of the loop

Comment: So that works if I put the return true statement outside of the first for loop and only if the object keys are different. However, in the example above, both objects in the userPassedFilter array have the same key property. So when I run the code on them, I get an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over the `dataList` and return every object where [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of its object properties are included in the `userFilter`.

```js
const userPassedFilter = [{voltage:122},{phase:1},{phase:2},{voltage:44}];

const dataList = [
  {voltage:44, phase:12},    
  {voltage:35, phase:2},
  {voltage:12, phase:2},
  {voltage:12, phase:3},
  {voltage:35, phase:1},
  {voltage:122, phase:156}
];

function filterData(dataList, userPassedFilter) {
  return dataList.filter(obj => {
    return userPassedFilter.some(inner => {
      const [[ key, value ]] = Object.entries(inner);
      return obj[key] === value;
    });
  });
}

console.log(filterData(dataList, userPassedFilter));
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce variable for each loop, so the result will match any of the elements in the `userPassedFilter` by matching all properties for the element.

```js
let userPassedFilter = [{"phase":1},{"phase":2}];
let dataList = [{"voltage":35, "phase":2},{"voltage":12, "phase":2},{"voltage":12, "phase":3},{"voltage":35, "phase":1}];

const f = (dataList, userPassedFilter) => {
  let filteredData = dataList.filter((data) => {
    let filtered = true;
    for (let item of userPassedFilter) {
      let matched = true;
      for (let key in item) {
        if (data[key] === undefined || data[key] !== item[key]) {
          matched = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (matched) {
        filtered = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return !filtered;
  });
  return filteredData;
};

console.log(f(dataList, userPassedFilter));
```

A shorter version:

```js
let userPassedFilter = [{"phase":1},{"phase":2}];
let dataList = [{"voltage":35, "phase":2},{"voltage":12, "phase":2},{"voltage":12, "phase":3},{"voltage":35, "phase":1}];

const f = (dataList, userPassedFilter) => {
  let filteredData = dataList.filter((data) => {
    return userPassedFilter.some(item => Object.entries(item).every(([key, value]) => data[key] === value))
  });
  return filteredData;
};

console.log(f(dataList, userPassedFilter));
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a variable

```
filteredData = dataList.filter((data) => {
   let myvar = true;
   for(let item of userPassedFilter){
      for(let key in item){
         if(data[key] === undefined || data[key] !== item[key])
          myvar = false
      }
   }
   return myvar
})
```

Comment: That did not work either. Thank you for your response though

Answer (score 0):

try adding a variable to hold the values:

```js
let userPassedFilter = [{
  "phase": 1
}, {
  "phase": 2
}]

let dataList = [{
    "voltage": 35,
    "phase": 2
  },
  {
    "voltage": 12,
    "phase": 2
  },
  {
    "voltage": 12,
    "phase": 3
  },
  {
    "voltage": 35,
    "phase": 1
  }
]


function filterData(dataList, userPassedFilter) {
  let filteredData = [];

  filteredData = dataList.filter((data) => {
    var throwVar = 0 //add this variable to hold the value
    for (let item of userPassedFilter) {
      for (let key in item) {
        if (data[key] === undefined || data[key] !== item[key]) {
          throwVar = 0
        } else {
          return true
        }
      }



    }
    if (throwVar == 0) {
      return false
    }
  })

  return filteredData

}


console.log(filterData(dataList, userPassedFilter))
```